# NullPointerException when using Cloud Save in Android

Tags: java, android, cloud, achievements, leaderboard

I need to init AppStateClient for using Cloud for save and load data. I do next:

```
public Constructor() {
(1) private GameHelper aHelper = new GameHelper(this);    
(2) aHelper.setup(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_APPSTATE | GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
(3) private AppStateClient mHelper = aHelper.getAppStateClient();
}
```

But in second string I always got NullPointerException. In GameHelper class from Goggle it crashes on:

```
 mGamesClient = new GamesClient.Builder(getContext(), this, this)
                    .setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
                    .setScopes(mScopes)
                    .create();
and on:  

mAppStateClient = new AppStateClient.Builder(getContext(), this, this)
                    .setScopes(mScopes)
                    .create();
```

What I do wrong?

aHelper variable I using in my app for achievements and leaderboards too and all work fine.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved.

```
public Constructor() {
 private GameHelper aHelper = new GameHelper(this);    
 aHelper.setup(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_APPSTATE | GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
 private AppStateClient mHelper = aHelper.getAppStateClient();
}
```

This code need to call in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) instead constructor of the class

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
private GameHelper aHelper = new GameHelper(this);    
     aHelper.setup(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_APPSTATE | GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
     private AppStateClient mHelper = aHelper.getAppStateClient();
}
```